# sighing in with google stuck in log in screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

i have a problem with google, when i login i get the mail that i used my account in a site
but it don't change the value of isSignedIn =>true
and i used firebase as back end i did add a support email and linked my database to my project but it seems to have some logical error
**this is the code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';


final GoogleSignIn gSignIn = GoogleSignIn();


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
{
  bool isSignedIn = false;
  



  void iniState(){
    super.initState();
   

    gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSigninAccount) {
      controlSignIn(gSigninAccount);
    }, onError: (gError){
      print("ERROR MESSAGE"+ gError);
    });

    gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((gSigninAccount){
      controlSignIn(gSigninAccount);

    }).catchError((gError){
      print("ERROR MESSAGE"+ gError);
    });
  }


  controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) async {
    if(signInAccount != null){
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = true;
      });
    }
    else{
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = false;
      });
    }
  }

  loginUser(){
    gSignIn.signIn();

  }

  logoutUser(){
    gSignIn.signOut();
  }

 


  Scaffold  buildHomeScreen(){
   return RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: logoutUser, icon: Icon(Icons.close), label: Text("Sign Out"));

  }
  Scaffold buildSignInScreen(){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [Theme.of(context).accentColor, Theme.of(context).primaryColor],
              )
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "SS",
                style:TextStyle(fontSize: 65.0, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Signatra" ),

              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: loginUser,
                child: Container(
                  width:270.0,
                  height: 65.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/google_signin_button.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                  ),
                ),

              )
            ],)
      ), );}
```

this is the method i used to check if the value has been changed

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isSignedIn)
    {

      return buildHomeScreen();

    }
    else
    {

      return buildSignInScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

yaml

```
name: buddiesgram
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7+2
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.3
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  flutter_svg:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
  assets:
    - assets/images/google_signin_button.png
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Firebase with your flutter project the best way is to use FlutterFire. You need to follow [those](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview#installation) steps to configure it.

***Like you said to me you will have compatibility issues with other firebase packages.
So you need to fix them like this :***

First of all you need to add the package `firebase_core: ^0.7.0`

Then change those packages in your pubspec.yaml

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.3
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
```

to

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
```

This will fix all the compatible issue. And if you run the command `flutter pub get` you shouldn't have an error.

---

You can now do this to check if your user is connected or not

```
  /*
   * If FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser return null
   * that mean you user is not logged. Otherwise you get
   * a value of type User with the user data
  */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
          ? buildSignInScreen()
          : buildHomeScreen();
  }
```

***You can find the documentation about user management [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#user-management)***

Comment: is there a package i have to add ?

Comment: i imported package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart but i still dont know what to do with the USER in `User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`

Comment: Yes you need to use FlutterFire. I updated the answer with what you need to install

Comment: idk it ask me to update a    `sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7+2
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.3
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  flutter_svg: `lot of other things is there any other way u can think of ?

Comment: can you update your post with your pubspec.yaml

Comment: when i added  `final bool isSignedIn = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? false : true` in the last method it skips the login screen get me direct to the home page with out login

Comment: pubspec.yaml is up there

Comment: I updated my answer with why you should do to resolve your packages versions issue.